# Jetty 9 throws null pointer on file with certain extension (woff ttf)

Tags: jetty

Jetty shows odd behavior for ttf and woff files. The stack trace below is generated when accessing .ttf file (static). I renamed the file to .bin it worked fine. I then created a regular html file and saved it with .ttf extension, same problem appeared.

java version "1.7.0_03" + jetty-9.0.0.M3 on ubuntu.

Full stack trace :

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf. Reason:
    Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.toBuffer(BufferUtil.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache$Content.<init>(ResourceCache.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache.load(ResourceCache.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache.lookup(ResourceCache.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:472)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$1.run(HttpConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:528)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2):

Jetty is missing a default mime type entry in mime.properties. I've just fixed that for jetty9. The quick fix for you is to add a mime type for ttf in webdefault.xml:

ttf
    application/octet-stream

Cheers,
Thomas